# Does the Minister of Defence participate in armed conflict?

Tags: tropico-4

When hiring a Minister of Defence, the chosen citizen retains the skin of a soldier/general including their gun.  During armed conflict (uprising, coup or rebel attack) does the Defence Minister actually function as a soldier and engage the enemy or does he lose this role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much info on the internet about this but from my own experience the minister for defense does not participate in conflict, although El Presidente does.

In addition to this if you hire a general for the minister position, the amount of solider jobs decreases but if they are already filled then you get messages about a 'crisis in command' or something meaning you need to hire more generals to order the soliders.